# python simple threading won't ends without doing anything (maybe)

Tags: python, multithreading

When i run the following code (using "sudo python servers.py") the process seem to just finish immediately with just printing "test".
why doesn't the functions "proxy_server" won't run ? or maybe they do but i do not realize that. (because the first line in proxy function doesn't print anything)

this is an impotent code, i didn't want to put unnecessary content, yet it still demonstrate my problem:

```
import os,sys,thread,socket,select,struct,time

HTTP_PORT = 80
FTP_PORT=21
FTP_DATA_PORT = 20

IP_IN = '10.0.1.3'
IP_OUT = '10.0.3.3'

sys_http = 'http_proxy'
sys_ftp = 'ftp_proxy'
sys_ftp_data = 'ftp_data_proxy'


def main():

    try:
        thread.start_new_thread(proxy_server, (HTTP_PORT, IP_IN,sys_http,http_handler))
        thread.start_new_thread(proxy_server, (FTP_PORT, IP_IN,sys_ftp,http_handler))
        thread.start_new_thread(proxy_server, (FTP_DATA_PORT, IP_OUT,sys_ftp_data,http_handler))
    print "test"
    except e:
        print 'Error!'
        sys.exit(1)



def proxy_server(host,port,fileName,handler):
    print "Proxy Server Running on ",host,":",port


def http_handler(src,sock):
    return ''



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What am i missing or doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you actually call `main`? This isn't C; naming a function `main` doesn't make it your program's entry point.

Comment: We need to see a [mcve] to diagnose this problem. Code that just vaguely looks like code that reproduces the error is nearly useless to us.

Comment: i have updated the code, changed some of the content while keeping the same problem occure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have indentation problems related to using mixed tabs and spaces for indentation. While they didn't cause your code to misbehave in this particular case, they *will* cause you problems later if you don't stick to consistently using one or the other. They've already broken the displayed indentation in your question; see the `print "test"` line in `main`, which looks misaligned.

Second, instead of the low-level `thread` module, you should be using [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html). Your problem is occurring because, as documented in the [`thread` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html),

> When the main thread exits, **it is system defined whether the other threads survive**. On SGI IRIX using the native thread implementation, they survive. On most other systems, they are killed without executing try ... finally clauses or executing object destructors.

`threading` threads let you explicitly define whether other threads should survive the death of the main thread, and default to surviving. In general, `threading` is much easier to use correctly.